# Conditional Logic on MySQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am doinga MySQL query to retreive data using PHP. I need to have a logic that if the data set returned is empty it shows a warning message else it displays the results:

```
$searchQuery = mysql_escape_string($_POST['searchQuery']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM db.tblname WHERE column1 = '".$searchQuery."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row["column1"];
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Mixing mysqli with mysql

Comment: @Saty can you assist me in fixing my issue then please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need num_rows on the object**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows == 0) { 
  echo 'result empty';
} else {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo $row["column1"];
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `mysql_escape_string` to `mysqli_escape_string` here

```
$where = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchQuery']) && trim($_POST['searchQuery'])){
   $searchQuery = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['searchQuery']);
   $where =" WHERE column1 = '".$searchQuery."'";
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM db.tblname ".$where;
```

Comment: Yh but that is not the way to go about showing a warning message if the dataset returned is empty

Comment: He'd also need to provide the link to his database for use in mysqli_escape_string

Comment: When I change this to `mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['searchQuery']);` it doesn't work

Comment: replace this `echo $row["column1"];` to `print_r($row["column1"]);` and then check

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
if ($result) {
    //Your code
} else {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check with `mysqli_num_rows()`. Here is how to

```
$searchQuery = mysql_escape_string($_POST['searchQuery']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM db.tblname WHERE column1 = '".$searchQuery."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row["column1"];
  }
}
else {
  echo "No records found";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchQuery = mysql_escape_string($_POST['searchQuery']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM db.tblname WHERE column1 = '".$searchQuery."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row["column1"];
    }
} else {
   echo "No results found";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```